# How to add a page preloader when user click on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add page preloader when the user clicks on the login button in my project.so I create a sample page by including a submit button. and created a spinner as a preloader by using CSS as well as a javascript function to execute the spinner & fade it out and load another page call welcome.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="overlay"> <div class="spinner"></div>
  </div>
 <input type="submit" name="click me" id="submit">


    **here is the javascript function**

 <script>
(function(){
  var spinner =document.getElementById("spinner");
  var loading = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame,20);

  function frame(){
    if(loading==100){
      clearInterval(id);
      window.open("welcome.html","_self");
    } else {
      loading = loading + 1;
      if(loading==90){
        spinner.style.animation ="fadeout 1s ease";

      }
    }
  }
})();

 </script>
</body>
</html>



 **here is the style sheet for preloader**

 .overlay{
   position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #ff6347;
z-index: -999;

 }

 .spinner {
    position: fixed;
top: 33%;
left: 48%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;

    -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

    **here is the keyframe code for fadeout**

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {opacity: 1;}
  to{opacity: 0;}
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }
}

@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 50% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 100% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

what I needed was, the user clicks on the button and then shows the preloader. But the thing is when I run the page button appears at the same time spinner preloader is running without clicking on the button and after the loading welcome.html page opens.

Comment: you need to hide the spinner on page load, i.e. by setting opacity to zero or display none and then show it when button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide the spinner initially and only show it when the loading starts. So you could change the frame function to something like this:

```
function loading(){
    if(loading==0) {
      spinner.classList.add('active');
    } else if(loading==100){
      clearInterval(id);
      window.open("welcome.html","_self");
      spinner.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
      loading = loading + 1;
      if(loading==90){
        spinner.style.animation ="fadeout 1s ease";
      }
    }
}
```

Also you could add some sort of click listener to the submit button rather than setting an interval to check every 20 milliseconds on page load already, that seems unnecessary.

And then change this in your css:

```
.spinner {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 33%;
    left: 48%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.spinner.active {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: Probably you should move the active class to the overlay parent in stead of the spinner like in the answer of @IHM365. But the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

First add

`.overlay{
    display:none;
}`

in css and then on click function of submit button add

```
document.getElementById("overlayId").style.display = "block";
```

If you are using javascript

and

`$(".overlay").css("display", "block");`

if you are using jquery

N.B.: overlayId is the Id of overlay DIV